# In Kibana visualize I can't see aggregation fields I expect to create charts

Tags: kibana

I have loaded an open source dataset into Kibana to experiment with and I want to create a bar chart.  The data set object is shown below.

I've loaded the data into Kibana with the bulk Elasticsearch upload api and managed to get the data in.  I can search the data within Kibana although when I try to create data charts the options within the "field" property within the visualize screen are: Month, Pct, Quantity & Year strangely.

I assume these fields are derived from the dataset - how do I get the fields I need i.e. Make, Year, Quantity etc as an option.  I assume these fields need to be indexed/ mapped or something?

**Dataset object**

```
{
  "_index": "car_sales",
  "_type": "models",
  "_id": "1369",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "Year": 2009,
    "Month": 12,
    "Make": "Ford",
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Pct": 0
  }
}
```

I want to display a bar chart showing the total sales for each car brand.  I.e. a vertical line for Ford sales, another vertical line for Toyota sales etc (the actual vertical line would be just a count of the number of Toyota entries in the data)

**Field properties**
[image: Field property screen shot]

**http://localhost:9200/car_sales/_mapping**

```
{"car_sales":{"mappings":{"models":{"properties":{"Make":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"Month":{"type":"long"},"Pct":{"type":"float"},"Quantity":{"type":"long"},"Year":{"type":"long"}}}}}}
```

**Field options**

[image: what I see in kibana when trying to make a bar chart]

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check your index mapping. The `Make` field should be of type keyword to use it in your visualization to chart sales data by make.

**EDIT**

To visualize car sales data by Make do the following

Set Y-Axis to `Count` as you have already done.

Set X-Axis to `Terms` and select Make.keyword as field

Run the visualization and you should see the sales count by Make now.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the question, please have a look - is this what you mean?  The property is currently "searchable" and type = string

Comment: OK, you should be able to see `Make.keyword` as a field available for Kibana visualization. You can use this field to chart sales data by Make

Comment: Post output of `GET car_sales\_mapping`. You can run this in Kibana Dev Tools

Comment: Have provided the mapping json data in the question.

Comment: Yep, your mapping confirms Make.keyword field can be used in Kibana visualization

Comment: Have added a screen shot with what I see.  Can't see Make as an option - unless I'm selecting something wrong?

Comment: I can now see Make.keyword under the "significant terms" option although I cannot produce the chart - see my edit in the question - It looks like the field "size" is mandatory so if I enter a value, i.e. 10 the chart is still not shown.

Comment: Is your Kibana publicly accessible ?

Comment: Make sure the time range you selected have documents with Make field otherwise you will see an empty chart if data doesn't exist

Comment: There's no time range selected (as shown in the screen shot)

Comment: If you still need help, please send an email to me on ben5556@gmail.com so we can discuss offline to prevent long comments chain